# Python: download a file from an FTP server

Tags: python, download, ftp, python-requests

I'm trying to download some public data files. I screenscrape to get the links to the files, which all look something like this:

```
ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/nhanes/2001-2002/L28POC_B.xpt
```

I can't find any documentation on the [Requests library website](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 122, accepted):

The `requests` library doesn't support `ftp://` links.

To download a file from an FTP server you could use [`urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve):

```
import urllib.request

urllib.request.urlretrieve('ftp://server/path/to/file', 'file')
# if you need to pass credentials:
#   urllib.request.urlretrieve('ftp://username:password@server/path/to/file', 'file')
```

Or [`urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen):

```
import shutil
import urllib.request
from contextlib import closing

with closing(urllib.request.urlopen('ftp://server/path/to/file')) as r:
    with open('file', 'wb') as f:
        shutil.copyfileobj(r, f)
```

Python 2:

```
import shutil
import urllib2
from contextlib import closing

with closing(urllib2.urlopen('ftp://server/path/to/file')) as r:
    with open('file', 'wb') as f:
        shutil.copyfileobj(r, f)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but how can you provide credentials?

Comment: @SSHThis: try: `'ftp://username:password@server/path/to/file'` or use [@Rakesh's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12424311/4279). If you can't make it to work, [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: A bit of urlib vs. requests information here: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/06/07/python-101-how-to-download-a-file/

Comment: @cbare: what is the point of the link. Does `requests` support `ftp` at all?

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: the article shows a side-by-side comparison of `requests` and `urllib`. Maybe that's helpful to someone switching from `requests` to `urllib` to gain FTP support? Or do you think it's better to delete the comment?

Comment: @cbare: It's up to you

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Any chance we could get an update? This doesn't work in Py3 and ftblib isn't cutting it

Comment: @zelusp if replacing `import urllib2` with `import urllib.request` "doesn't work" for you then ask a separate question (provide specific errors that you get). It might be worth it to ask a new question anyway with your specific requirements (describe in the question how exactly "ftplib isn't cutting it": what do you expect to happen? What happens instead? (in detail)).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, You're completely right - it was really late and I just wanted a magical answer. But maybe I'll solve my problem now that I've slept - thanks for reply!

Comment: If downloading multiple FTP files, "IOError: [Errno ftp error] 200 Switching to Binary mode." would be thrown when using "urllib.urlretrieve".

Comment: I realise this is a really old post, sorry for bumping it. But in your answer to @SSHThis `'ftp://username:password@server/path/to/file'`, is the username and password encrypted or "hidden", or can anyone who sees your traffic read it just like they could read a url? Sorry I don't know too much about encryption and how all this works but I was curious.

Comment: @LimokPalantaemon it is equivalent to `ftp.login(user, passw)` call and therefore it is not encrypted (ftp is a very old protocol—little security). You could try sftp instead (fabric/paramiko).

Comment: Wow, I'm amazed that it takes three modules and six lines to download a file...  Thanks so much for your Python3 answer - I was getting desparate after trying `urllib`, `requests` and `wget` (the latter can't overwrite existing files...)

Comment: Why do you use `contextlib.closing` when `urllib.response.addinfourl.__exit__` already calls `self.close()`?

Comment: @gerrit: my guess is that the response object didn't support the context manager protocol in 2012.

Comment: why is `shutil` needed with `urilib.request`?

Comment: @grisaitis it is just a loop: `while data := r.read(blocksize): f.write(data)` (copy data from the input file object `r` to the output file `f`)

Comment: How would I go about downloading the files to save them locally?

Comment: @Jsleshem: you are commenting on the answer that does exactly that.

Answer (score 72):

You Can Try this

```
import ftplib

path = 'pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/nhanes/2001-2002/'
filename = 'L28POC_B.xpt'

ftp = ftplib.FTP("Server IP") 
ftp.login("UserName", "Password") 
ftp.cwd(path)
ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + filename, open(filename, 'wb').write)
ftp.quit()
```

Comment: What if filename on server have some special characters e.g. ' ', $, & etc. Do I need to escape them?

Comment: The fiilename can be an arbitrary byte sequence with a few exceptions such as `b'\xff'`  (I don't know any standard way to escape such names). Here's [more detail (in Russian)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/523291/23044). You could ask  a separate Stack Overflow question if you have a specific issue with ftp filenames

Comment: Encoding the filename from unicode to "utf-8" worked for me. Maybe that differs on different OS: `ftp.retrbinary(u"RETR täßt.jpg".encode('utf-8'), open('local.jpg', 'wb').write)`

Comment: If the data returned is larger than the blocksize I believe this will continue to overwrite the file and keep only the last block.

Comment: How can I specify which directory on the local machine to send it to?

Answer (score 18):

Try using the wget library for python. You can find the documentation for it [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wget).

```
import wget
link = 'ftp://example.com/foo.txt'
wget.download(link)
```

Comment: Simplest and works well.  You can also set the filename with the `out` parameter in wget.download.

Comment: This works for me and other method caused file crushed.

Comment: @anatoly-techtonik I think you're the author of this pypi module.  Would you consider it safe to use?

Comment: Caution: no release since 2015, and Homepage link on pypi is broken link (to bitbucket).  Author's other projects moved to github, but I don't see this one.  https://github.com/techtonik

Answer (score 7):

Use [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html). For more specifics, check out this [example from doc.python.org](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/howto/urllib2.html):

Here's a snippet from the tutorial that may help

```
import urllib2

req = urllib2.Request('ftp://example.com')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

Answer (score 7):

```
    import os
    import ftplib
    from contextlib import closing

    with closing(ftplib.FTP()) as ftp:
        try:
            ftp.connect(host, port, 30*5) #5 mins timeout
            ftp.login(login, passwd)
            ftp.set_pasv(True)
            with open(local_filename, 'w+b') as f:
                res = ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % orig_filename, f.write)

                if not res.startswith('226 Transfer complete'):
                    print('Downloaded of file {0} is not compile.'.format(orig_filename))
                    os.remove(local_filename)
                    return None

            return local_filename

        except:
                print('Error during download from FTP')
```

Comment: I have a completely unrelated question to this thread but related to your code uploaded on github: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27584233/sliding-window-how-to-get-window-location-on-image

Answer (score 4):

As several folks have noted, requests doesn't support FTP but Python has other libraries that do. If you want to keep using the requests library, there is a [requests-ftp](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-ftp) package that adds FTP capability to requests. I've used this library a little and it does work. The docs are full of warnings about code quality though. As of 0.2.0 the docs say "This library was cowboyed together in about 4 hours of total work, has no tests, and relies on a few ugly hacks".

```
import requests, requests_ftp
requests_ftp.monkeypatch_session()
response = requests.get('ftp://example.com/foo.txt')
```

Comment: This solution works, in my hands at least, as `s = requests.Session()` `response = s.get(...` (not as `requests.get`)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to take advantage of recent Python versions' async features, you can use [aioftp](https://aioftp.readthedocs.io/index.html) (from the same family of libraries and developers as the more popular aiohttp library). Here is a code example taken from their [client tutorial](https://aioftp.readthedocs.io/client_tutorial.html):

```
client = aioftp.Client()
await client.connect("ftp.server.com")
await client.login("user", "pass")
await client.download("tmp/test.py", "foo.py", write_into=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

`urllib2.urlopen` handles ftp links.

Comment: For those new-ish to Python: Was renamed back to just urllib, still supports FTP. Basically see the top answer.

Answer (score 1):

urlretrieve is not work for me, and the official [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) said that They might become deprecated at some point in the future.

```
import shutil 
from urllib.request import URLopener
opener = URLopener()
url = 'ftp://ftp_domain/path/to/the/file'
store_path = 'path//to//your//local//storage'
with opener.open(url) as remote_file, open(store_path, 'wb') as local_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(remote_file, local_file)
```