# Downloading second file from ftp fails

Tags: python, ftp, urllib

I want to download multiple files from FTP in python. the my code works when I just download 1 file, but not works for more than one!

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve('ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/pmc/oa_package/00/00/PMC1790863.tar.gz', 'file1.tar.gz')
urllib.urlretrieve('ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/pmc/oa_package/00/00/PMC2329613.tar.gz', 'file2.tar.gz')
```

An error say:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ehsan/dev_center/bigADEVS-bknd/daemons/crawler/ftp_oa_crawler.py", line 3, in <module>
    urllib.urlretrieve('ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/pmc/oa_package/00/00/PMC2329613.tar.gz', 'file2.tar.gz')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 98, in urlretrieve
    return opener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 245, in retrieve
    fp = self.open(url, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 213, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 558, in open_ftp
    (fp, retrlen) = self.ftpcache[key].retrfile(file, type)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 906, in retrfile
    conn, retrlen = self.ftp.ntransfercmd(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 334, in ntransfercmd
    host, port = self.makepasv()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 312, in makepasv
    host, port = parse227(self.sendcmd('PASV'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 830, in parse227
    raise error_reply, resp
IOError: [Errno ftp error] 200 Type set to I
```

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried using `ftplib` built-in module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bug in `urllib` in python 2.7. Reported [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue27973). The reason behind the same is explained [here](https://bugs.python.org/msg276795)

> Now, when a user tries to download the same file or another file from
>   same directory, the key (host, port, dirs) remains the same so
>   open_ftp() skips ftp initialization. Because of this skipping,
>   previous FTP connection is reused and when new commands are sent to
>   the server, server first sends the previous ACK. This causes a domino
>   effect and each response gets delayed by one and we get an exception
>   from parse227()

A possible solution is to clear the cache that may have been built up by previous calls. You may use the `urllib.urlcleanup()` method calls between your `urlretrieve` calls  for the same, as mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlcleanup).

Hope this helps!