# how to read a file on ftp with python?

Tags: python, ftp

here is my code:

```
import ftputil
import urllib2
a_host = ftputil.FTPHost(hostname, username,passw)

for (dirname, subdirs, files) in a_host.walk("/"): # directory
    for f in files:
            if f.endswith('txt'):
                htmlfile = open(f, 'r')
                readfile = htmlfile.read()
```

I think it should be ok, but I got an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

    htmlfile = open(f, 'r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'readme.txt'
```

where is the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: download a file over an FTP server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768214/python-download-a-file-over-an-ftp-server)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot read the remote file using `open` like local file. You need to download the file from the remote host first.

```
for (dirname, subdirs, files) in a_host.walk("/"): # directory
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('txt'):
            a_host.download(f, f)  # Download first
            with open(f) as txtfile:
                content = txtfile.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`a_host.open`](http://ftputil.sschwarzer.net/trac/wiki/Documentation#id3), not a Python default `open`.

Thus, instead:

```
htmlfile = open(f, 'r')
readfile = htmlfile.read()
```

This:

```
htmlfile = a_host.open(f, 'r')
readfile = htmlfile.read()
```