# How can i Download data from an ftp server in python or R?

Tags: python, r, ftp, noaa

I am trying to download precipitation data from an ftp server. The code that i am using is, but am still getting errors. Thanks

```
import urllib2
urlretrieve("http://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/fews/fewsdata/africa/arc2/geotiff/", "folder link")
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally recommend using pycurl for this. have you tried using the ftp protocol?:

```
urlretrieve("ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/fews/fewsdata/africa/arc2/geotiff/", "folder link")
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the URL, it seems you are using `http` protocol. If you want `ftp`, you may need to call it like this:

```
from urllib import urlretrieve
urlretrieve("ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/fews/fewsdata/africa/arc2/geotiff/", "folder link")
```

(Also, be careful of your package. You're doing `from urllib` and you're calling `urlretrieve`. It must be `urllib.urlretrieve(...)` in your case)

See this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768214/python-download-a-file-over-an-ftp-server), it may help you.

Also I do not think that the second argument of `urlretrieve` is a folder link. It is a file name.