# How to make a Python script to download a file from a FTP server

Tags: python, download, ftp, server

I am trying to download a file from my FTP server to a specific folder, without a GUI. This is what I have so far, but it does nothing,

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve('ftp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@ftp.SERVERNAME/File path/', 'FILENAME')
```

Comment: SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service; as such, your question is far too broad.

Comment: my bad, I don't frequently visit here, well, I hope your community can help!
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768214/python-download-a-file-over-an-ftp-server

Comment: It can't help, that's what I'm saying. You should delete the question, and review [ask].

Comment: Maybe someone can :)

Answer (score 8):

I edited my answer to be more simpler ..now we will need to use **FtpLib**

the code below is straightforward and it's elegant :D

```
import ftplib

path = 'pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/nhanes/2001-2002/'
filename = 'L28POC_B.xpt'

ftp = ftplib.FTP("Server IP") 
ftp.login("UserName", "Password") 
ftp.cwd(path)
ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + filename ,open(filename, 'wb').write)
ftp.quit()
```

> Just in case you need some explanation:
>
> **path** is obviously the location of the file in the ftp server
>
> **filename** is the name + extension of the file you want to **download** form server
>
> **ftp.login** is where you'll put your credentials(username, password)
>
> **ftp.cwd** will change the current working directory to where the file is located in order to download it :)
>
> **retrbinary** simply will get the file from the server and store in your local machine using the same name it had on the server :)
>
> Do not forget to change Server IP argument to your server's ip
>
> and Voila that's it.

Comment: sorry, what do I put in the 'file' section because I'm getting an invalid syntax

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm afraid I still don't understand, could you dicatate it to me? User= USERNAME pass= PASSWORD file= heythere.bat. And a huge thanks for your help so far :))))) (^_^)

Comment: Please check my answer now :)