# Download/read GovData with R

Tags: python, r, structure, download

I stumbled over the following site and I wanted to download the data for the digital elevation model for the waterways.

https://www.govdata.de/web/guest/daten/-/details/1c669080-c804-11e4-8731-1681e6b88ec1bkg

Now, I have following problem, I do not understand how I can download the data.

Anybody knows how I could download the data, e.g. by using the programming language R or Python.

Comment: Considering figuring out how to download a file using Python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768214/python-download-a-file-over-an-ftp-server OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python

Answer (score 0):

**You will need to be on the webpage where the data is stored**, not the webpage with the links to the data. Depending on what format the data is in you will need to change the (sep='\t') to fit your needs,

ex. a csv would be (sep=',')

You will then need to fine tune the formatting.

```
library(RCurl)

urlcontent<- 
getURL('https://www.govdata.de/web/guest/daten/-/details/1c669080-c804-11e4-
8731-1681e6b88ec1bkg')

DATA<- read.table(textConnection(urlcontent), header=T, sep = '\t')
```

Note the read.table function may only work with a tsv type page, you will need to fine tune the reading of the page based on the formatting.

EDIT:

Using the link address for the URL I was able to successfully grab the URL, the problem though is an access error, I do not have access to download the data.  This may be another error in the code, or an actual credential problem on the website side.

```
library(RCurl)

urlcontent<- 
getURL('https://www.govdata.de/ckan/api/rest/dataset/1c669080-c804-11e4-
8731-1681e6b88ec1bkg')

DATA<- read.table(textConnection(urlcontent), header=T, sep = '\t')
```

Error:You don't have permission to access this server

Comment: However, I still do not understand how to get the URL where the data are stored. They provide an API and also some kind of CKAN format, and as I understood, this should allow you to download the data very easily. I found a package called CKANR (https://github.com/ropensci/ckanr), however, I do not understand how this works. On the Webpage (https://www.govdata.de/web/guest/daten/-/details/1c669080-c804-11e4-8731-1681e6b88ec1bkg) you find 5 Links which are doneted with ATOM, XML, WMS and CKAN, and I thought in some way those provide ways to get the data in an uniform way.

Comment: @Mr.Man Awesome, thanks for the info. I'll look into it more today