# Python- pull csv from ftp url with credentials

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, ftp

Newb to python and working with APIs. My source create an ftp url where they are dumping files on a daily basis and I would like to grab file to perform engineering + analysis. My problem is, how do I specify username and password to pull the csv?

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('http://site-ftp.site.com/test/cat/filename.csv)
```

How do I include credentials to this? 
PS- url is fake for the sake of an example.

Comment: Why don't you consider downloading the file first through a standard python interface before running it through a specific library/system. Consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768214/python-download-a-file-over-an-ftp-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With older versions of Pandas, you can use something like `requests.get()` to download the CSV data into memory. Then you could use `StringIO` to make the data "file like" so that `pd.read_csv()` can read it in. This approach avoids having to first write the data to a file.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csv = requests.get("http://site-ftp.site.com/test/cat/filename.csv", auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'password'))
data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv.text))

print(data)
```

From pandas 0.19.2, the `pd.read_csv()` function now lets you just pass the URL directly. For example:

```
data = pd.read_csv('http://site-ftp.site.com/test/cat/filename.csv')
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks Martin! Code for python 3:
    
    import pandas as pd
    import requests
    from io import StringIO

    csv = requests.get("http://site-ftp.site.com/test/cat/filename.csv", auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'passwprd'))
    data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv.text))
    print(data)